# ASP.NET C# Get second column in gridview if checkbox is checked with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am facing this situation and have no idea how to solve it.
I have Gridview with this columns and this sample values:

```
CHECKBOX   NAME   SURNAME
-------------------------
Checkbox1  John   Smith
Checkbox2  Jerry  Rose
Checkobx3  Will   Mathews
```

I have a problem to get value from second column from dynamically created gridview where checkbox is checked. So I check Checkbox2 and now I want to get value from Name column for this row. In this case that would be "Jerry".

Also, if I checked Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 I want to get "John" and "Jerry" split by comma.

My code so far:

```
    $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tbody >tr >td >input:checked').each(function () {      
           alert($(this).find("td").eq(2).html());
      var values+=$(this).find("td").eq(2).html()+","; //values splitted by comma
    });
```

Below is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader"
                            onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes1(this);" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I run this code results are just "undefined". What is wrong?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is corrected `JavaScript` code:

```
var result = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr td input[id*="chkSelected"][type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {

    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).text();

    }).get().join();
```

Regards,
Uros